# Direct Binding Partner Orchestrations in Biztalk Server

Tags: biztalk

I have two Orchestrations (Parent & Child), there is a variable existed in my Parent Orchestration and my Question is that I want to access that variable in my Child Orchestration, for your information I'm using  Direct Binding Partner Orchestrations.

NOTE: I Don't want to use Call or Start Orchestrations Shape, Somehow i have to implement this with 
Direct Binding Partner Orchestrations.

How would you do this?

Comment: Can you provide more details for making the question more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new field to the XML message that you are publishing via the direct bound port and assign the value of the variable to that field in the XML message.

Comment: +1 but also just to note, if you assign the variable in your parent orch, you'll either need to do this in that messages construct shape or you'll need to create a new message as a copy.